# PHP - Sort array data based on days and time

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a table with data entries in a specific layout based on days and times.

For example we have store opening times:

Mon - Fri 0900 - 1200

Mon - Fri 1300 - 1700

The table should show:

```
Day  Open Closed Open Closed
Mon  0900 1200   1300 1700 
Tue  0900 1200   1300 1700 
Wed  0900 1200   1300 1700 
Thur 0900 1200   1300 1700 
Fri  0900 1200   1300 1700
```

If the opening times also include the following:

Wed - Wed 0900- 1100

Wed - Wed 1300- 1700

The table would show

```
 Day  Open Closed Open Closed
    Mon  0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Tue  0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Wed  0900 1100   1300 1700 
    Thur 0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Fri  0900 1200   1300 1700
```

And so on as other entries are added.

So far I've got the data coming in as an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09 : 00
            [1] => 12 : 00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11 : 00
            [1] => 17 : 00
        )

)
```

Where:

```
[0] is the First Day (Monday = 1)
[1] is the Second Day (Friday = 5)
[2] is the opening time
[3] is the closing time
```

I'm looping through the array and creating new arrays based on Days, opening and closing times,

```
foreach ($array as $arr => $val) {
        if ($arr === 0) $start = $val;
        if ($arr === 1) $end = $val;
        if ($arr === 2) $open = $val;
        if ($arr === 3) $close = $val;
    }
```

But I can't see how to go from here to get the required output.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
The following days and times,

```
Mon - Fri   09 : 00 17 : 00    
Wed - Wed   13 : 00 17 : 00    
Wed - Wed   09 : 00 12 : 00
```

Create this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09 : 00
            [1] => 13 : 00
            [2] => 09 : 00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17 : 00
            [1] => 17 : 00
            [2] => 12 : 00
        )

)
```

**UPDATE**
The resulting output should look like this:

```
 Day  Open Closed Open Closed
    Mon  0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Tue  0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Wed  0900 1100   1300 1700 
    Thur 0900 1200   1300 1700 
    Fri  0900 1200   1300 1700
```

**Further Example**

PHP Array

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "0900" [1]=> string(7) "1300" [2]=> string(7) "0900" [3]=> string(7) "0200" [4]=> string(7) "0900" } [3]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "1700" [1]=> string(7) "1700" [2]=> string(7) "1200" [3]=> string(7) "2100" [4]=> string(7) "1300" } }
```

JSON

```
[[1,3,3,6,0],[5,3,3,6,0],["0900","1300","0900","0200","0900"],["1700","1700","1200","2100","1300"]]


Mon  0900   1700       
Tue  0900   1700       
Wed  0900   1200       
Wed  1300   1700       
Thur 0900   1700       
Fri  0900   1700       
Sat  0200   2100       
Sun  0900   1300
```

Comment: so in the first half of the array there are the days that are referring to the second half? can you please post a real input/output example (so that i can use it to test a possible solution)?

Comment: @Berto99 - I've updated the question with data captured using var_dump. Thanks

Comment: sorry, that array is the input or output array?

Comment: @Berto99 that is the output I have to work with, its being passed by JS to PHP and then json decoded. The data that is passed is `[[1,3,3],[5,3,3],["09 : 00","13 : 00","09 : 00"],["17 : 00","17 : 00","12 : 00"]]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$arr = [[1,3,3],[5,3,3],["09 : 00","13 : 00","09 : 00"],["17 : 00","17 : 00","12 : 00"]];
$days = [
    1 => 'Mon',
    2 => 'Tue',
    3 => 'Wed',
    4 => 'Tur',
    5 => 'Fri',
    6 => 'Sat',
    7 => 'Sun',
];
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($arr[0]) ; $i++){
    echo $days[$arr[0][$i]]." - ".$days[$arr[1][$i]]." : ".$arr[2][$i]." - ".$arr[3][$i]."\n";
    // shorter and cleaner way: 
    // echo "{$days[$arr[0][$i]]} - {$days[$arr[1][$i]]} : {$arr[2][$i]} - {$arr[3][$i]} \n";
}
```

Output:

```
Mon - Fri : 09 : 00 - 17 : 00
Wed - Wed : 13 : 00 - 17 : 00
Wed - Wed : 09 : 00 - 12 : 00
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. Its very nearly what I need.  Any way to expand the Mon-Fri so they are show as individual days ? and order Wed so 0900=1200 appears before 1300-1700 ?

Comment: @tom you mean that instead of  `Wed - Wed : 13 : 00 - 17 : 00
Wed - Wed : 09 : 00 - 12 : 00` you want `Wed - Wed : 09 : 00 - 12 : 00     13 : 00 - 17 : 00`

Comment: if that is the case @tom, it's not as easy as this version, but i can try

Comment: I've updated my ticket with the layout I'm trying to get. Thanks

Comment: @Tom please post coherent result, on your testing input there is no information about Saturday and Sunday, post the desired output for that input sample

Comment: Updated question with details.